# When you buy Windows 10 from Microsoft does it come with all updates preinstalled?

Tags: windows, windows-10

The reason I ask is because I only use Windows in a partition, and from time to time, I wipe it and reinstall. If I knew that by buying it, I would have on-demand access to a pre-updated version, then it would make it more convenient for me.

Comment: No. You get a particular build version.

Comment: The [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) will generate an ISO with the latest publicly released build. I don't think it includes the latest cumulative update, but the reworked scheme for Windows Updates means that there will only be one update to download (along with any drivers needed) once you get Windows up and running. If you're in a situation where you absolutely need an updated image, you can download the latest update manually and slipstream it into the ISO, but that's a lot of work to create an image that will be outdated in a month anyway.

Comment: Additionally, if you're implying that you already have an OEM license and want to buy a retail license just to get access to a clean and updated image, that's completely unnecessary with Windows 10. Microsoft has finally started offering clean installation media to everyone for free via the aforementioned [Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), and it (in most cases) works with both OEM and retail license keys without any hacks or manipulation as was required with older versions of Windows.

Answer (score 4):

The version that everyone has access to via the [Windows Media Creation tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10) webpage is typically the latest release. It may not have the current monthly cumulative update set, but it will be mostly up to date.

Specifically it will currently download "Fall Creators" (1709) update. When the next update is released then the tool you get on that page will download the latest update.

Comment: Isn't that just a particular build version?

Comment: It has been progressively updated on each 6-monthly release at least. It doesn't need you to download the first build of Win10 and then update to the latest from there, it will be the latest release downloaded.

Comment: That's what I meant. So it potentially needs up to six months of patches.

Comment: Not even that, the current month update should be cumulative iirc, so it only needs to download the latest patch.

Comment: Ah. Yes. If you use the cumulative patches.

Comment: @DavidPostill Uhhh. Who doesn't?

Comment: Me :). I haven't patched my Windows 7 for quite some time apart from specific kbs I needed.

Comment: The Media Creation Tool downloads a particular asset, at a particular location, which is then converted to an ISO.  The Windows 10 ISO for a particular feature update is indeed update.

Answer (score 0):

You can download updated retail image of Windows 10 from Microsoft and use it to install Windows with any adequate licence, the licence date is not important.

Answer (score 0):

> When you buy Windows 10 from Microsoft does it come with all updates preinstalled?

No, not all (presuming some updates have been released after the image was made).  However, the image may include some available updates built in.

With earlier versions of Microsoft Windows, the installation software would be updated to include some updates.  Probably this usually meant including service packs.

Note, however, that you can also create your own custom installer that contains whatever updates, or even some other software, that you want.  Creating such installation data is called "slipstreaming".  This has historically been used for quite a while, as occasionally people (probably typically professionals with access to more expensive gear) would need to install special drivers for some hardware, such as disks.  (Once you have Windows installed, you may be able to install other software easily, but if you want to install Windows to a particular disk, that disk needs to be supported.  If it wasn't pre-supported, you could create installation media that contains the necessary drivers.)

Professional service shops have then been able to create their own custom installation files that contains whatever updates they choose.  They can choose to do so whenever they like.

Therefore, since it is easier to upgrade than to try to downgrade, the earlier discs are actually more valuable in case you ever want to check out, or otherwise use, an older version.  If upgrading is too much of a hassle, just slipstream your desired upgrades to create a custom installer.